# Match key value pair between multiple tables with same columns

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have 4 tables with same set of columns, e.g. Car model name, description and Price.

Two tables can have same car models. Need to find car models that have different prices in different tables.

Here is what I am thinking of doing:

1. Join two tables on car model name but price as not equal
2. Repeat #1 for all combination of tables
3. Take union of all these joins
4. Find distinct car models from #3

Is it the right approach? Can someone please help with the sample code for it?

Comment: [Consider giving a minimal, complete and verifiable example please](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need a union:

```
SELECT a.model, a.price, b.price, c.price, d.price
FROM 
  a 
  INNER JOIN b on a.model = b.model
  INNER JOIN c on a.model = c.model
  INNER JOIN c on a.model = c.model
WHERE
  a.price <> b.price OR a.price <> c.price OR a.price <> d.price
```

This way you not only know that a price is different, but which price is different; it sounds like you'd lose that info with your approach (you didn't indicate you were selecting anything to identify which pair of tables went into the union)

The union would be helpful if not all tables have all pairs of cars, e.g. a and b might have a Ford Mustang, but this car is absent from C and D - the join would hide the mustang due to the absence in C/D regrdless of if the price was different or same. I didn't get the impression from your question that this was how things are, though

In this regard, rather than going for all the different pairs, unioned, I'd union first, group them up and look for models HAVING a MIN(price) that s different from the MAX(price):

```
SELECT
  model,
  min(price),
  max(price)
FROM
  (
    SELECT model, price FROM a UNION ALL
    SELECT model, price FROM b UNION ALL
    SELECT model, price FROM c UNION ALL
    SELECT model, price FROM d
  )
GROUP BY
  model
HAVING min(price) <> max(price)
```

You lose knowledge of which table(s) the differences are in with this approach. This can be countered, but it might not be a requirement

Comment: The `union all` is preferable.  First, it has better performance if car models have lots of rows in all the tables.  Second, it doesn't filter out models that are not in all four tables.